# Web service não acessa minhas classes

Tags: java, web-service, eclipse, packages

Estou montando um web service, anteriormente ele ja estava funcionando normalmente mas os scripts estavam todos em um só pacote, então decidi organizar em pacotes diferentes os meus scripts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem agora meu web service não acessa as classes que estão em um pacote diferente dos códigos do web service, e recebo essa mensagem no SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>br.com.sata.Classes.Usuario</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Código JAVA

```
package br.com.sata.WebService;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.sata.Classes.Usuario;
import br.com.sata.Crud.Crud_Usuario;
import br.com.sata.Validacao.ValidaUsuario;

public class WS_Usuario 
{
    public String inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException
    {
        String message = ValidaUsuario.testaCampos(usuario);
        if(message != "OK")
        {
            return message;
        }
        return Crud_Usuario.inserirUsuario(usuario);
    }
}
```

XML do Web Service

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://WebService.sata.com.br" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ax219="http://Classes.sata.com.br/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ax217="http://sql.java/xsd" targetNamespace="http://WebService.sata.com.br">
<wsdl:documentation>Please Type your service description here</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Classes.sata.com.br/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="Infos">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bairro" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="canc" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="celular" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="complemento" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="conc" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cp" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idCidadeFK" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nome" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numero" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reputacao" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="rua" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="telefone" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Usuario">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="ax219:Infos">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="senha" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sql.java/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="SQLException">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SQLState" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="errorCode" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nextException" nillable="true" type="ax217:SQLException"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:ax220="http://Classes.sata.com.br/xsd" xmlns:ax218="http://sql.java/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://WebService.sata.com.br">
<xs:import namespace="http://sql.java/xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://Classes.sata.com.br/xsd"/>
<xs:element name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SQLException" nillable="true" type="ax218:SQLException"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="inserirUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax220:Usuario"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="inserirUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="excluirUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="senha" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="excluirUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="atualizarUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax220:Usuario"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="atualizarUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="excluirUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:excluirUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="excluirUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:excluirUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="atualizarUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:atualizarUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="atualizarUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:atualizarUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="inserirUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:inserirUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="inserirUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:inserirUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="WS_UsuarioPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:excluirUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:excluirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:excluirUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:excluirUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:WS_UsuarioSQLException" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:excluirUsuarioWS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:atualizarUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:atualizarUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:atualizarUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:atualizarUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:WS_UsuarioSQLException" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:atualizarUsuarioWS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:inserirUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:inserirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:inserirUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:inserirUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:WS_UsuarioSQLException" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:inserirUsuarioWS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="WS_UsuarioSoap11Binding" type="ns:WS_UsuarioPortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:excluirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:atualizarUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:inserirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WS_UsuarioSoap12Binding" type="ns:WS_UsuarioPortType">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:excluirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:atualizarUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:inserirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="WS_UsuarioSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="WS_UsuarioSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WS_UsuarioHttpBinding" type="ns:WS_UsuarioPortType">
<http:binding verb="POST"/>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<http:operation location="excluirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
<http:operation location="atualizarUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<http:operation location="inserirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="WS_Usuario">
<wsdl:port name="WS_UsuarioHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:WS_UsuarioSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/WS_Usuario.WS_UsuarioHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WS_UsuarioHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:WS_UsuarioSoap12Binding">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/WS_Usuario.WS_UsuarioHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="WS_UsuarioHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:WS_UsuarioHttpBinding">
<http:address location="http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/WS_Usuario.WS_UsuarioHttpEndpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Erro no console

> [ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method
>   inserirUsuario org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: br.com.sata.Classes.Usuario
>     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.DefaultObjectSupplier.getObject(DefaultObjectSupplier.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.processObject(BeanUtil.java:818)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.ProcessElement(BeanUtil.java:737)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:646)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException: br.com.sata.Classes.Usuario     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.DefaultObjectSupplier.getObject(DefaultObjectSupplier.java:42)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   br.com.sata.Classes.Usuario.()  at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)   ... 28 more

Como posso resolver isso? e isso vai afetar todos os outros scripts que estão em pacote diferente do web service? ou só os scripts que são usados como parâmetros nos métodos do web service?

Comment: Está correto os imports no seu webservice?

Comment: Se vc fala dos imports do código java eu coloquei, tanto que no código não tem nenhum erro, o problema é na hora de consumir o web service, Coloquei o código Java e o XML para poder visualizar melhor o problema

Comment: Coloca um `try/catch` no seu método ao invés de dar `throws` e veja se está acontecendo algo.

Comment: coloquei mas a mensagem continua sendo a mesma

Comment: Tu tem que olhar se ele entrou no catch, entrou?

Comment: "não acessa as classes" ?
onde você está acessando elas?

Comment: Não entrou no catch, se não ele teria dado outra resposta, eu coloquei um return no catch pra e.getMensage

Comment: Está como public?

Comment: Está, a unica coisa que tem é herança, mas eu tinha testado antes com herança e estava funcionando

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver galera, o problema era que faltava colocar um construtor vazio na classe, não sei por que isso acontece mas era isso que estava causando o erro, talvez por que na hora que incia ele pede os valores, então deixei um construtor vazio por primeiro e outro normal para inserir os dados

```
package br.com.sata.Classes;

public class Usuario extends Infos
{
    private String login;
    private String senha;

    public Usuario()
    {

    }

    public Usuario(int id, String nome, String email, String cp,
            int idCidadeFK, String bairro, String rua, int numero,
            String complemento, double reputacao, String telefone,
            String celular, int conc, int canc, String login, String senha) {
        super(id, nome, email, cp, idCidadeFK, bairro, rua, numero,
                complemento, reputacao, telefone, celular, conc, canc);
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```